# Use typescript unions in a seamless way

Tags: typescript, unions

The backend I am talking has an API to create orders.
Such orders have products, that when received by clients are just specified by IDs, and when sent by the server, they are full detailed objects.

The typescript interface would be something like this:

```
export interface Order {
  userId: number;
  bought_products: BoughtProduct[];
}

export interface BoughtProduct {
  quantity: number;
  product: number | Product; // not specified here
  created?: string; // other keys are optional because only present if sent by Backend
}
```

It would be perfect if the typescript interpreter would understand when I am using product as numbers or receiving Products as objects, without an explicit cast.
This because, since it's a nested array, using casts would be complicated.

An more straightforward example of the problematic can be seen in [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20interface%20Order%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20userId%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bought_products%3A%20BoughtProduct%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20BoughtProduct%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20quantity%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20product%3A%20number%20%7C%20Product%3B%20%2F%2F%20not%20specified%20here%0D%0A%20%20%20%20created%3F%3A%20string%3B%20%2F%2F%20other%20keys%20are%20optional%20because%20only%20present%20if%20sent%20by%20Backend%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20interface%20Product%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20somekey%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20orderProducer%20(id%3A%20number)%3A%20Order%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20userId%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20bought_products%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20quantity%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20product%3A%20id%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20backendOrder%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20userId%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bought_products%3A%20%5B%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20quantity%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20product%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20somekey%3A%20'example-product'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%2C%0D%0A%7D%20as%20Order%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20orderConsumer(o%3A%20Order)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20o.bought_products.forEach(bp%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(bp.product.somekey)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AorderConsumer(backendOrder)%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: Sounds to me like you have two different types here and you probably should have two different interfaces to represent them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
interface Order {
    userId: number;
    bought_products: Array<ClientBoughtProduct | ServerBoughtProduct>;
}

interface BoughtProduct<T> {
    quantity: number;
    product: T;
}

interface ClientBoughtProduct extends BoughtProduct<number> {}

interface ServerBoughtProduct extends BoughtProduct<Product> {
    created: string;
}
```

Then I'd use [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
function isClientBoughtProduct(obj: BoughtProduct<any>): obj is ClientBoughtProduct {
    return typeof obj.product === "number";
}

function isServerBoughtProduct(obj: BoughtProduct<any>): obj is ServerBoughtProduct {
    return typeof obj.product === "object";
}

if (isServerBoughtProduct(obj)) {
    // obj.created is available
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is smart enough to auto cast it for you if you type checked it earlier e.g.

```
if (typeof boughtProduct.product === "number" {
     // it will be handled as number
} else {
     // it will be handled as Product
}
```